# Generate custom group ranking in sql

Tags: sql, ranking-functions

As posted, I am trying to generate group ranking based on Is_True_Mod column. Here Until next 1 comes, I want 1 group to be there. Please find expected output in SQL. Here in expected output, rows grouped based on **Is_True_Mode** column. Regular ranking showing for reference ( order by ranking should be their )

[image: SQL Result]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and a database tag.

Comment: Please find attached image for reference

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the groups using a cumulative sum.  Then you can you `row_number()` to enumerate the rows:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by grp order by regularranking) as expected_output
from (select t.*,
             sum(is_true_mode) over (order by regularranking) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```